# How to set default value for radio button in Sanity Studio?

Tags: radio-button, default, sanity

I'm trying to set the default value given a list of radio items in Sanity Studio.

**Code:**

```
export default {
  name: 'banner',
  title: 'Banner',
  type: 'document',
  fields: [
    {
      name: "category",
      title: "Category",
      description: "Choose a category",
      type: "string",
      options: {
        layout: "radio",
        list: [
          { title: "Documentary", value: "documentary" },
          { title: "Fiction", value: "fiction" },
        ],
      },
      // set initial value here ?
    },
  ]
}
```

There is a property called `initialValue` that can set the default value of a string easily, but I can't figure out how to do this with radio items.

**How can I have the radio item `Fiction` already selected when the page is loaded?**

Answer (score 0):

````
  name: 'banner',
  title: 'Banner',
  type: 'document',
  fields: [
    {
      name: "category",
      title: "Category",
      description: "Choose a category",
      type: "string",
      options: {
        layout: "radio",
        list: [
          { title: "Documentary", value: "documentary" },
          { title: "Fiction", value: "fiction" },
        ],
      },
      initialValue: "documentary", // set initialValue's value to one of the `value`s in your list of radio items
    },
  ]
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try using `initialValue` directly on the document object rather than on the field:

```
export default {
  name: 'banner',
  title: 'Banner',
  type: 'document',
  fields: [
    {
      name: "category",
      title: "Category",
      description: "Choose a category",
      type: "string",
      options: {
        layout: "radio",
        list: [
          { title: "Documentary", value: "documentary" },
          { title: "Fiction", value: "fiction" },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
  initialValue: {
    category: 'fiction'
  }
}
```